# BI Publisher not compiling <xsl:attribute>?

Tags: xslt, bi-publisher

I'm using MS Word to create rtf templates for Oracle BI Publisher.

My goal is to conditionally assign a color to the title in the header section.
My xsl code looks like this:

```
<?if:DRUCKTITEL ="NICHT FREIGEGEBEN"?><xsl:attribute name="color">red</xsl:attribute><?end if?><?DRUCKTITEL?>
```

I expect the words "NICHT FREIGEGEBEN" to appear in red, however what I get is this:
[image: result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems BI Publisher has a problem with changing font color even when the code gets interpreted as code.

I settled on a work around of putting text formatted in red in Word inside the if clause instead of the xsl-code.
This works and while it looks weird in the layout it leads to the wanted result.

[image: Code-snippet]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<?attribute@incontext:color;'red'?>
```

Or, you can use this inside of a field's "Help Text" or BI Publisher code section.

```
<xsl:attribute xdofo:ctx="block" name="color">red</xsl:attribute>
```

I highly recommend installing the desktop tool if you have not already done so.

Comment: Tried the first proposal. It doesn't show up like in my initial example, but it also doesn't change the color of the text.

The second proposal is a no-go. MS Word does not allow form fields in headers or footers.

Comment: Try using a table with two cells (1 column, two rows) in your document. Put this header stuff in the first cell, making sure row properties are set to repeat as header row at the top of each page (essentially making your own header section). Then put the rest of your content in the second row.

Comment: Sorry for the late response.
Sadly this did not work either. It seems BI Publisher has a problem with changing font color even when the code gets interpreted as code.

I settled on a work around of putting text formatted in red in Word inside the if clause instead of the xsl-code. This works and while it looks weird in the layout it leads to the wanted result.
Thank you for your effort though.